# How do we handle sysadmin tasks in a non-traditional (academic/research-oriented) workplace?

Tags: backup, users

*Disclaimer: I'm struggling to figure out where this question fits -- it could be here, Workplace SE, or Academia SE -- so I'm happy to move it if necessary.*

I work in a research group at a large university in the U.S. We're about the size of a small business - between 15 - 25 people at any given point in time. We currently run about 1 workstation per person and around 2 - 3 server racks (averaging 4 servers per rack). These servers are usually where we run our experiments - frequently using <strike>buggy</strike> research-oriented code. We've also got a VM hosted off-site responsible for running a variety of services (Git repos, SVN repos, websites, etc.).

Recently we've been running into issues with drives failing, our VM crashing, and general server maintenance. Additionally, we're in the process of doubling the number of servers we have (big purchase, we're all excited). The head of the group has asked several of us to look into how to address these problems.

One potential issue that we've already identified is that most sys admin tasks (replacing faulty drives, managing access control, debugging crashed servers) are currently handled on an ad-hoc basis by whoever has free time and the proper privileges. We also recognize that many of the problems are, in essence, "research" problems - things that no true sysadmin could likely account for and handle.

What I'd appreciate advice on is how we can better handle our group's computing needs. We love to joke that we need to hire a sysadmin, but I think we're all aware that research tends to preclude the things sysadmins would like (a.k.a. *stability* and *predictable user behavior*). So without hiring a sysadmin, are there guidelines that I can offer to my boss on how to manage our servers/workstations/resources more effectively?

Comment: One thing you should find out is whether and to what extent your university's IT Services can help you.

Comment: I agree with Michael.  To add to that, if your IT group will not allocate a resource to analyze or assist, you might ping one of them "out-of-band" and offer a case of beer.  It can go a long way.  Maybe they can at least help you outline and prioritize your needs at a higher level so you can predict the success of your projects.

Answer (score 2):

There are systems engineers who have backgrounds in or [work within research and academic environments](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/114246/linux-systems-architect-the-d-e-shaw-group?offset=4&f=True&sort=i). It's not as uncommon as you think, and in reality, the skill set you're seeking is something that any well-trained admin with insight into your users' needs can do.

This is going to be all about the money. If your university has resources available, leverage them. Otherwise, how are you funded? Do you have an allocation for the salary or consulting fees for a part-time admin?